# The purpose of this Java code - Object Creation

Tags: java, object, instantiation

I would like to understand the following code. Is there a name for creating an object with two classes? I assumed I would create a Deer object that can call methods/variables from the Animal class but it does not seem to be working. Why would someone want to create an object like this in Java?

```
public class Animal {
   int J = 20;
}

public class Deer extends Animal {
    int Q = 40;
}

public void test() {
    Animal D = new Deer();
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is called inheritance, which is extremely useful when you're doing anything OOP-related in Java.**

You currently don't even have any methods in either class so you can't test how methods would work right now. However, if you added a method in the animal class (e.g. `public void talk() {}`), you could call that method in the Deer class using `super.talk()`.

As a side note, if you're declaring a class as `public`, it needs to be in its own separate file or you'll get a compiler error. If you want everything to be in one file, just take out the word `public`.

You can visit https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_inheritance.asp for more information on inheritance and classes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful when you need to re-use code and get information from **both classes**, For example, class **ANIMAL** and **subclasses Dog, Cat, Monkey**, and so on.
In the end, all of them are animals with similar methods like eating, run, sleep but in a deeper way each one of them has unique behaviors, the cat can eat but it also can meow, the Dog can run but it also can bark.
so they have unique and similar actions to perform.
inheritance is a good way to re-use an existing code from the parent class.
you can check inheritance docs.
[Inheritance](https://www.mygreatlearning.com/blog/inheritance-in-java/#:%7E:text=Inheritance%20in%20Java%20is%20a,class%20or%20the%20child%20class.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I found the question description is too short. So try correcting it.
This type of class creation is part of something called as inheritance it helps when

1. we don't want to provide access of the function of a subclass.(So our base class act as a wrapper.)
2. To override the function of baseclass. So that when baseclass function is called, it behaves as if the subclass function has been called.

lets take example

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    Animal D = new Deer();
    System.out.println(D.getType());
    
    }
    
    public static class Animal{
        String Type="Animal";
        public String getType(){
           return Type;
        }
    }
    
    public static class Deer extends Animal{
        String SubType="Mammal";
        public String getType(){
           return SubType;
        }
        public String eatgrass(){
            return "eatgrass";
        }
    }
     public static class Bird extends Animal{
        String SubType="bird";
        public String getType(){
            return SubType;
        }
        public String fly(){
            return "flying";
        }
     }
}
```

In the above example.

1. We can see that not all animals eatgrass, so we would like to hide that detail and only use the function that are common to all animal objects, Here in this case its getType()
2. We want the D.getType() to return the closest type of class name of deer in animal chart which is "mammal". So when we call D.getType() instead of getting "Animal" as what you would be expecting looking at the code, we will be getting "Mammal"